# How to add image in Excel file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel

I have used xlsxreaderwriter library to create xlsx file and make good excel file.
Most things work well, but I can't add image to the file.
I wrote code like sample but I can't see image in the xlsx file.
I already put one image into sample file and use it, still I can't add any Image programatically in my xlsx file.
Here is my code that I used.

My code:

```
NSString *documentPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testWorkbook" ofType:@"xlsx"];
BRAOfficeDocumentPackage *spreadsheet = [BRAOfficeDocumentPackage open:documentPath];

BRAWorksheet *fooWorksheet = [spreadsheet.workbook createWorksheetNamed:@"Foo"];
BRAWorksheet *worksheet = [spreadsheet.workbook createWorksheetNamed:@"Foo" byCopyingWorksheet:worksheetToCopy];
[[fooWorksheet cellForCellReference:@"B2" shouldCreate:YES] setStringValue:@"FOO / BAR"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"123.jpeg"];  NSData * data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
BRAWorksheetDrawing *drawing = [fooWorksheet addImage:img betweenCellsReferenced:@"A1" and:@"D10"withInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero preserveTransparency:NO];

drawing.insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0., 0., .5, .5);

[spreadsheet save];
[spreadsheet.workbook save];

NSString *fullPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"workbookCopy.xlsx"];
[spreadsheet saveAs:fullPath];
NSLog(@"%@",fullPath);
```

please help me to sort the issue

Comment: You are not creating an Excel file. You are creating a CSV file. A CSV file is a text file. You can't add images to plain text files such as CSV.

Comment: rmaddy...See th extension its xls and it is open in excel sheet as perfect format

Comment: Putting an xls extension on a CSV file doesn't change the fact that you are generating a purely text CSV file. A true Excel (xls) file is a proprietary binary file format. Your code is not creating a true xls file. And just because the Excel application (or many other programs) can open a CSV file doesn't make it anything other than what it is. You can't embed images in a CSV text file. You would need to write completely different code that generates a true xls (better yet, a more modern xlsx) file. And that is far from trivial. You need a proper library for that.

Comment: rmaddy......do you know how to generate pure xls file with image in it

Comment: As I said, you need to find a 3rd party library that supports the generation of real Excel files. Find one that generates xlsx (not xls).

Comment: xlsxreaderwriter used but image won't get added up.And none otheer library is there. @rmaddy

Answer (score 1):

There is an option. Use a C library called `libxlsxwriter`. The CocoaPod can be found [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/libxlsxwriter). There is an [example](https://github.com/lrossi/libxlsxwriterCocoaExamples) for how to use this library with objective-c, but it contains no examples for how to insert images.

I have made an [example](https://github.com/FrankenApps/LibXlsxWriterSwiftSample/blob/master/LibXlsxWriterSwiftSample/Examples/demo.swift) for how to insert images using swift. You should be able to easily convert the code to objective-c:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import xlsxwriter

class Demo{
    func generate() -> URL {
        let documentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
        let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("demo.xlsx")
        
        //Create a new workbook.
        //Ditch first 6 characters, because they are of the form file://
        let workbook = workbook_new((fileURL.absoluteString.dropFirst(6) as NSString).fileSystemRepresentation)
        let worksheet = workbook_add_worksheet(workbook, nil)
        //Add a format.
        let format = workbook_add_format(workbook)
        //Insert an image
        var imageBuffer = getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData: (UIImage(named: "logo")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)!)! as NSData)
        worksheet_insert_image_buffer(worksheet, 1, 2, &imageBuffer, imageBuffer.count)
        workbook_close(workbook)
        
        return fileURL
    }
    
    func getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData:NSData) -> [UInt8]
    {
        //Determine array size
        let count = imageData.length / MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: UInt8())
        //Create an array of the appropriate size
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
        //Copy image data as bytes into the array
        imageData.getBytes(&bytes, length:count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: UInt8()))

        return bytes
    }
}
```